# How to save all columns of pageBlocktable in visualforce page as pdf?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, pageblocktable, renderas, column

I am trying to save my page as pdf, My page having Pageblocktable with 16 coloumns, When i try to save using code, it is just displaying only some columns in pdf.

How to save all cloumns in pdf? please check the code

```
<apex:page controller="ReportPageCon"
           showHeader="false" 
           renderAs="pdf">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!objList}" var="item">
   <apex:column value="{!item.Field1__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.State__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.District__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Mandal__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Village__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.First_Name__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.Aadhar_ID__c}"/>
                                          <apex:column value="{!item.Gender__c}"/>
                                          <apex:column value="{!item.Date_Of_Birth__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.Age__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.field__6__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.field__4__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.fileld3__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.field5__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.field_2__c}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.Mobile_Number__c}"/>

    </apex:pageblockTable>          
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>                
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: what do you mean *it is just displaying only some columns in pdf.* ?

Comment: In my original code i have added 16 columns, It  is executing fine without errors, But it is displaying only 9 cloumn in pdf.  I want to display all columns in pdf. When i save as Excel it is displaying all coloumns.

Comment: can you add a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to save my page as pdf, My page having Pageblocktable with 16 coloumns, When i try to save using code, it is just displaying only some columns in pdf.

How to display all cloumns in pdf? please check the code

[image: please check the screen shot]

Comment: Try set a width on the table and avoid using visualforce styling elements as they're not fully supported by the PDF renderer. Try to stick as much as you can to plain HTML when generating a PDF.

Comment: I changed width on table and I also changed  to html table,Even it is displaying some fileds in pdf.   Can you modify the code or provide any example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through my code:

I checked with different widths on table and I also changed pageBlockTable to html table, **Even it is displaying few columns in pdf**. Please povide solution or provide an example. Thank you.

page 1:

 
    
            
                
            Coloumn name2
            Coloumn name3
            Coloumn name4
            Coloumn name5
            Coloumn name6
            Coloumn name7
            Coloumn name8
            Coloumn name9
            Coloumn name10
            Coloumn name11
            Coloumn name12
            Coloumn name13
            Coloumn name14
            Coloumn name15
            Coloumn name16
                
            
            
                
                    
                        {!item.Field1__c}
                        {!item.Field2__c}
                        {!item.Field3__c}
                        {!item.Field4__c}
                        {!item.Field5__c}
                        {!item.Field6__c}
                        {!item.Field7__c}
                        {!item.Field8__c}
                        {!item.Field9__c}
                        {!item.Field10__c}
                        {!item.Field11__c}
                        {!item.Field12__c}
                        {!item.Field13__c}
                        {!item.Field14__c}
                        {!item.Field15__c}
                        {!item.Field16__c}

page2: PageThatGeneratesPdf:

@page{
    size:A4 portrait;

```
@bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " - " counter(pages);
    font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

}

Here is your main content ...